# Bindable LINQ (BLinq) in VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, linq, data-binding

I cannot get Bindable LINQ to work with VB.NET for the life of me. How do I get the .AsBindable extention to appear?

Sample code:

```
Class TestList : Inherits Bindable.Linq.Collection.BindableCollection(Of TestItem)
  'Some Helpers and stuff'
End Class

Class TestItem
  'Some Properties'
End Class
```

Imagine I magically come up with a collection full of items. I'll stry something like the following

```
DataContext = From G In TheList.AsBindable Order By G.Name
```

But I get an error on .AsBindable that "AsBindable is not a member of TestList"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make fun of me, but all I had to do was Import Bindable.Linq